# I like the ascii git-log that tig renders - can I somehow export it into a file?

Tags: git, graph, ascii, tig

I'd like to render an ascii git-log in the way tig does it.
Is there a commandline for such an operation?

something like `tig log from_commit...to_commit > gitlog.text`.

I tried various commands, but it doesn't seem friendly with redirecting output to a file...

Comment: If you aren't looking for colored output: it is mainly `git log --stat`. Do you mean "and I want the same colors" ?